# Scheduling Oracle sql files using Unix based SAS enviornment

Tags: oracle, sas

I have bunch of SQL queries that run against an Oracle database. Is there a way to schedule these `.sql` files using UNIX Based SAS, so they can execute one after another at certain time of day?

Answer (score 0):

If they are .sql files, why do you want to schedule them using SAS? Are they SAS programs? If not, I would do one of three things, depending on my constraints:

1) Convert the .sql files to stored procedures and call them from DBMS_SCHEDULER within Oracle, since Oracle has a fantastic job scheduling subsystem (actually multiple variants) that protects against duplicate jobs among other issues, and you get transactional control, auditing and logging. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sched.htm

2) If converting them to stored procs is too much, then call the .sql scripts directly from DBMS_SCHEDULER with DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_PROGRAM() and then schedule that program with DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB.

3) Use cron or atrun to schedule batch / shell script wrappers that call sqlplus to run .sql files.

If the question is specifically how to do this with SAS, then DBMS_SCHEDULER can still execute external SAS programs using option (2) above.